# SSDT very long to time to load project and unresolved references

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

Hi I'm having real issues with SSDT, specifically since I moved my machine across to Windows 2012 and upgraded to VS2015.

The project takes about 10 mins to load being stuck on analysing 10,000s objects. Moreover the database project references another DB project and won't build.

The main issue is unresolved references in a view that references the other database project. There are lot's of unresolved references errors.

Can anyone recommend how to troubleshoot this? Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

My bad - just realized I inadvertently removed a variable reference to the view. I still have a few separate but related questions but I will post separately. Cheers.